# typescript import from angular is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm relative new to typescript. 
I have created a abstract class where I'm using the ActivatedRoute from angular. This class is used from some components I have defined and it is placed in it's own directory. 
When it is placed in a file with another component defined it is working as expected.
During startup I get following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ActivatedRoute is not defined

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { IModel } from "../../interfaces/IModel";

export abstract class AddEditComponent<T extends IModel> {
    entity: T;
    protected route: ActivatedRoute;

    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, type: string)
    {..}
}
```

Is it a bad practice to do so? Or how can I fix it?

Kind regards

Comment: Check for circular imports.

Comment: Check if you imported route module to main app module

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk I have tried to add `import { Http } from "@angular/http";` and `import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";` to my app.shared.module.ts file but without success

Comment: I meant something like this

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],

Comment: And   import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

Comment: When I import the `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';` and update RouterModule.forRoute with `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true }` then I got the errors: Expected 1-2 arguments but got 3 and Cannot find name appRoutes